# Run JavaScript function immediately and in eventListener

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I have a function which must be executed immediately then in an eventListener.

Here is how I run both:

```
function mediaBodyClass() {

    var body = document.body;

    if (window.innerWidth >= 992) {
        body.classList.add('desktop');
        body.classList.remove('mobile');
    } else {
        body.classList.add('mobile');
        body.classList.remove('desktop');
    }

};

mediaBodyClass(); // Now

// In the listener
window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    mediaBodyClass();
});
```

What is the best practice?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with what you're doing now, at least in terms of how you structure your JavaScript code.  It's simple, clear, and easy to understand and maintain.  Though you can simplify the event listener binding to: `window.addEventListener('resize', mediaBodyClass);`

Comment: You can try using a media query.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) to apply styles to the body when the screen width is smaller than a certain limit, instead of using JavaScript:

```css
body{
    /* .desktop styles go here */
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  body {
    /* .mobile styles go here  */
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes of course, for CSS. It was an example with classes. But I might need it to modify attributes or others depending on the media.

Answer (score 2):

Whilst what you are doing is fine - you might find the matchMedia api useful - basically its a javascript version of a media query in which you can attach functions to given viewport widths and also listen for changes to the viewport size.

Here is a link to a useful article.https://css-tricks.com/working-with-javascript-media-queries/

```
const mediaQuery = window.matchMedia('(min-width: 992px)')

function handleViewportSizeChange(e) {
 var body = document.body;
  if (e.matches) {
    body.classList.add('desktop');
    body.classList.remove('mobile');
  }else {
    body.classList.add('mobile');
    body.classList.remove('desktop');
  }
  
}

// Register event listener
mediaQuery.addListener(handleViewportSizeChange)

// Initial check
handleViewportSizeChange(mediaQuery)
```